# How to Edit homepage: skeleton generated by express generator

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

I am new to **Node.js** application development with **expressjs framework**.
I created a skeleton with **expressjs-generator**.

This skeleton have following *directories and files*:

```
 .
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

After it: I use the following command to run this application.

```
set debug=myapp:* & start npm
```

Now this is successfully running at Port **3000**
This shows the homepage with *Express Welcome message*.

I want to make change in Homepage of my application. How it can be possible?

Comment: change index.jade to update your homepage

Comment: is all the change in homepage would be possible by changing this file?

Comment: can you give a complete guide about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing the index.jade as @brute_force mentioned. If you are not familiar with jade, you can also add a index.html in the public folder and update the index.html instead.